# How to quit entire program from inside a function's if statement

Tags: python

Im trying to get my python script to exit entirely from inside of a function. The function is called to read a file. If the file doesnt exist id like to kill everything. Ive attempted `sys.exit()`, `os_exit()`. None of these are killing the entire program, they just seem to kill the function they are contained in. Is there a way to kill the program in its entirety?

Here is a simple example to illustrate

```
def readf(file)
    try:
        slist = open(file).readlines()
        return [s.replace('\n', '') for s in slist]
except IOError as e:
    if e.errno == '2':
        print "No Such file or directory: " + servers
        sys.exit()#want to kill everything running in main
    else:
        print e

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #other functions being called at the same time as readf
    returnd = readf(file.txt)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "being called at the same time as readf"?  Are you running multiple threads? Also, the syntax of your example is invalid in several places (`radf(file.txt)`, indenting)

Comment: I don't know what's going on with your code, but `sys.exit()` absolutely does completely exit the program.

Comment: Apologies, ive fixed the typos. Im not running multiple threads, I am assuming its only killing the `readf` function as the program keeps running.

Comment: Which version of Python? I vaguely recall old versions would not exit when you expected them to when running from the command line in Windows, but that would have been 2.4-ish I think (and who would want to run on Windows anyway).

Comment: How do you know it is killing the function and not the program ?

Comment: @joaquin again i did say "it seems to be", I was making the assumption it was as the `print` was executing on the error as expected but the script continued to run.

Comment: **there is no such thing as *killing a function*, that isn't even valid terminology!**

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson, so you expect new comers to programming to know everything? If they don't, you penalise them? nice. I did say it "seems", i was trying to describe something that I didn't understand. What would you expect? Regardless of you lack of sympathy or ability to look at a situation from another person perspective (someone not as clued up as yourself) thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There is no such thing as *killing a function*

You either stop the entire program or you don't.

I am pretty sure `if e.errno == '2':` is wrong and should be `if e.errno == 2:`

Comparing numbers to strings is almost always incorrect.

Also Python is indention sensitive, this had all kinds of syntax errors and indention problems on its first iteration, no way to trust if what is in the question accurately represents the code that is actually being executed, the code in the question still isn't indented correctly to execute as desired.

Comment: "almost always" is good... I cannot imagine a situation where it would be correct...

Comment: I did say seems to be killing the function. As the program continues to run. Strange as the `print` statement fires as expected. Ill make the change and let you know none the less.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson, Thanks changing the string to int has fixed it. Still dont understand why the `print` still fired (shrugs).

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson The indentation issues in this post were due to copy and paste, then me missing them. Im using an IDE so dont tend to have issues with indentations in general.